# Basic optimization question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, economics

A teacher put this problem up the other day and I'm confused about how he got to the answer. Can you explain it to me?

Job $X$ provides $20$ vacation days and $143,000$ euro annual salary.

Job $Y$ provides $16$ vacation days and $145,400$ euro annual salary.

The question asks: what salary would $Y$ need to proved to make a rational agent indifferent to the the two options.

He said the answer is $155,000$ euro.

I approached this a few different ways. One was to calculate how much $X$ paid per day $(143000/(260-20))=595.8$ [$260$ business days/year, less the vacation time]. Since $Y$ provides four less days, they would need to compensate an additional $4*595.8$ = $2,400$. Thus, $143,000 + 2,400 = 145,400$ which is the given salary of $Y$. I'm not sure why I need to add $4*2,400$ to $145,400$ for $Y$'s salary to break even with $X$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you say what your thoughts on the problem
are and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level
And this site uses
[MathJax formatting of formulas](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Thanks, @JKnecht. I added my first approached

Comment: One problem here is that "competitive" is not well-defined. I make full use of my 20 vacation days, so switching to a job that offered fewer days would be a significant negative to me. Some of my coworkers only use most of their vacation days when they reach the "use it or lose it" limit. A few have even accepted the loss of vacation days. For them, job Y would be preferable even at a salaries less than $145,400$ euros. Did your teacher explain the concept of "competitive" he is using?

Comment: The actual phrase was: "I would be indifferent if salary for Y = ___". I'll edit that above.

Comment: My guess is that the assumption of 260 business days/year is wrong. Either that, or your teacher's incorrect.

Comment: I looked up that number myself. I don't know if he used that to solve it at all. If you just took the question stem, how would you go about solving it?